# How export animation of Sapling Tree Gen in unity?

Tags: export, unity, sapling-addon

I’ve created a tree in blender using the “Sapling Tree Gen”, with an armature, an animation and without leaf (I added them after with particle system and convert it, but this is another story xD) now, how can I export the mesh of the tree with the animation and import them in unity?